# Comparison of Double Constants

Tags: java, constants, double

I researched this a lot and I know something about precision errors in the doubles; however I couldnt find the answer. My question is: is it **always** safe to compare double constants? What do I mean by that is, just reading the double from a string or creating in the source code. No operation (adding, subtracting etc.) will be done on them. If I create a variable like

double c = 3.0.

Will the following equation will always be true? c==3.0000.

For example is there any possibility to see wrong evaluation of an equation like this 1.23456789 < 1.23456788?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's always safe; with one caveat.

Here's an example:

```
1.232342134214321412421 == 1.232342134214321412422
```

That is **true**; all double constants are silently rounded to the nearest representable double, and for both of these numbers, it is the same double.

Thus, given 2 actual mathematical numbers A and B where `A < B`, then if you turn those numbers into double literals and run these 3 expressions on it, you get the following scenarios:

#### If A and B are rounded to different doubles, you get guarantees:

- `A < B` will be true
- `A == B` will be false
- `A > B` will be false

#### If A and B are really close to each other, they may round to the same double, and you get:

- `A < B` will be false
- `A == B` will be true
- `A > B` will be false

In other words, 'less than' and 'greater than' can be bent into being equal, but a lesser number will never be erroneously treated as larger.

Comment: "all double constants are silently rounded to the nearest representable double". Thanks for this. Seems like if I dont go very very precise numbers, I wouldnt get into trouble.

Comment: Quite so. There are about `2^64` blessed numbers (numbers that are exactly representable). As you move away from the 0 in either direction, the frequency of blessed numbers goes down. The interval (distance between blessed numbers) is higher than 1 once you get beyond 2^52. In other words, there are many billions of blessed numbers between 0 and 1, but only 1 between 2^52 and 2^52+1. All double constants get silently rounded to the nearest blessed number. The blessed number sequence makes sense.. in binary. In decimal it looks arbitrary.

Answer (score 1):

> For example is there any possibility to see wrong evaluation of an equation like this 1.23456789 < 1.23456788?

Yes, that is possible, because you can write floating-point literals with arbitrary numbers of digits, and these will be approximated to the nearest value that fits in a `double` when they are interpreted by the compiler.

For example:

```
boolean result = 1.2003004005006007008009 > 1.2003004005006007008008;
System.out.println(result);
```

Prints `false`, even though mathematically the first number is larger than the second number (so you'd expect it to print `true`).

In conclusion: by using floating-point literal values, you won't suddenly have arbitrary-precision floating-point numbers.